# bind() code from prototype.js

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

```
Function.prototype.bind = function(){
  var fn = this, 
      // clone arguments
      args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments), 
      // get the first argument, which should be an object, and args will be modified. 
      object = args.shift();
  return function(){
    return fn.apply(object,
      // why use concat??? why? 
      args.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
  };
};
...
elem.onclick = Button.click.bind(Button, false);
....
```

I saw above code from here: 
http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/#86
while learning javascript. The code is an excerpt from prototype.js. The comments are added by me, not from original code.

My question is why use **args.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)))**? I think pass args is enough. 
The bind() in prototype.js must have its valid reason. Please help me understand it. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Well, you also want to to able to access the arguments passed to the bound function, not only the arguments bound to the function.

`args` refers to the arguments passed to `.bind` and `arguments` refers to the arguments passed to the bound function (the one returned by `.bind`).

Make the changes to `.bind` and compare the versions with the following function:

```
function foo() {
    console.log(arguments);
}

var bound = foo.bind(null, 1, 2);
bound(3, 4);
```

With `args.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));`, the output will be

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

with `args` only, it will be

```
[1, 2]
```

In case of the event handler, you won't be able to access the event object passed to it if you'd only use `args`.

Comment: Thanks! Your last sentence helps me a lot.